# How to install Linux on a USB flash drive so that the installation is compatible with the macOS boot loader

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I wish to install Linux on an USB flash drive, such that my Mac can run it from its boot menu.

When I burn a Linux live CD to an USB flash drive, my Mac displays it in the boot menu. However, when I install it to a USB flash drive, the installation does not show up in the boot menu.

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@mmiglier/ubuntu-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-mac-compatible-469ad33645c9), this happens because the EFI partition used by macOS expects the EFI partition to have a different format (HFS+) whereas Linux uses (VFAT). I do not wish to use this article's complicated approach/hacks because I always end up corrupting my drive when I fiddle around with such things… I wish to have a simple solution.

What I have tried is using the legacy master boot record installation without an EFI partition; however that did not work either. This might be because grub is doing some strange things.

Anyone have experience with this issue, or have any tips? Perhaps there is some other boot loader which would circumvent these issues?

PS: I am also aware of [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html), but that has to be install on top of my macOS boot loader. I do not like that because Boot Camp overwrites it sometimes and it has a messy reinstall process. Maybe I can install rEFInd on the USB? Would that work?

Comment: I've done it on Windows by simply writing GRUB to the USB root device (not a partition, the top level device file - /dev/sdc or whatever).  Don't know if the same would work for the Mac ...

Comment: @ivanivan unfortunately that does not work on macOS, the boot loader will not show an option to boot from the USB.

Comment: from my limited Mac experience, there is a key combo to press during power on to let you boot from a USB device instead of internal hard drive...